# Use Conjugate Gradient to obtain the Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-optimization

So I have been told that we can use CG to obtain an eigenvalue approximation to the true matrix. I am not sure how? (Connection to Lanczos)

Furthermore I have been told that there is a deep connection between CG and Lanczos. I would really appreciate if someone can clarify how are they connected. I do understand that if we do Lanczos we would get a good approximation to the eigenvalues, but I do not see how can we use CG and get the eigenvalues. Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you assume symmetry of the matrix?

Comment: I assume matrix meets all the criteria for CG, which includes symmetry.

Comment: Well, Lanczos works for rectangular matrices as well.

Comment: Good point, but I am looking at symmetric.